# Show there exists a unique formal power series $g$ such that $g^d=f$

Tags: generating-functions, formal-power-series

The problem is as follows:

'Let $f$ be a formal power series with $f_0=1$. Show that there is a unique formal power series $g$ with $g_0=1$ such that $g^d=f$, for some positive integer d.'

I am sure the answer here relies on the idea of unique fps inverses (i.e. we should be able to write the equality as $(g^d)(f)^{-1}=1$, where $1$ is the identity), but I can't see the approach from here.

Any hints or ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should mention that you want $d>1$.

Comment: Are you working in characteristic zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume characteristic zero, and $\,d\ne 0.\,$ 
Given $\,f\,$ as a formal power series
$$ f := 1 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots $$
and suppose $\,f = g^d.\,$ Differentiate to get
$$ D_x[g] = D_x[f]\,\frac{g}{d f}. $$
Integrate and use $\,g_0=1\,$ to get a recursion
$$ g = 1 + \int D_x[f]\,\frac{g}{d f} dx. $$
This recursion shows existence and uniqueness of $\,g\,$ given $\,f.$ In more detail,
define a sequence of functions by recursion
$$ g_0 := 0+O(x),\quad g_{n+1} := \!1\!+\!\int
 D_x[f]\, \frac{g_n}{d f} dx. $$
The next two terms are
$$ g_1\!=\!1 \!+\! \frac{a_1}d x \!+\! O(x^2), $$
$$ g_2\!=\! 1 \!+\!\frac{a_1}d x\!+\!\frac{
a_1^2(1\!-\!d)\!+\!2a_2d}{2d^2}\!+\!O(x^3). $$
This sequence converges to $\,g\,$ and any $\,g\,$
that satisfies $\,f=g^d\,$ agrees with $\,g_0\,$
and by recursion all of the $\,g_n.\,$

Comment: Thank you! Can you please elaborate on the integration step - how does this show uniqueness specifically? I am not 100% clear.